# How can I get information from entry and inserted that in another entry I want that work vice versa?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-layout

I am making a converter. You should be able to write some numbers in the first entry and other converts, and you should be able to do that vice versa.

```
from tkinter import*
def on_entry_click(event):
    global c
    c=1
    print(c)
def text_changed(*args):
    try:
        if c<0:
            far=int(entry_2.get())
            cel=far/2.5
            entry_1.delete(0, END)
            entry_1.insert(0,cel)
            entry_2.delete(0, END)
            entry_2.insert(0,far)
        else:
            cel=int(entry_1.get())
            far=cel*2.5
            entry_2.delete(0, END)
            entry_2.insert(0,far)
            entry_1.delete(0, END)
            entry_1.insert(0,cel)
    except ValueError:
        pass

c=0
el=0
far=0
pg=Tk()
frame_1 = Frame( pg )
frame_1.grid(row=0, column=0)



tk_name=StringVar()
tk_name.set("")
tk_name.trace("w", text_changed)

entry_1 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=tk_name)
entry_1.bind('<FocusIn>', on_entry_click)
entry_1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="W")

entry_2 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=tk_name,font='Arial 18')
entry_1.bind('<FocusIn>', on_entry_click)

entry_2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="W")
pg.mainloop()
```

Here you can convert from first entry to another but not vice versa.
Can somebody show me another method, if possible?
P.S Apologies for my poor English.

Comment: Use `entry = event.widget` to know which `Entry` got the `'<FocusIn>` event.

Comment: Thanks I already found the solution. I made one more  text variable and made another def.